# Layout Automation API access for end users

Tags: social-tables

Our ReServe Interactive Social Tables account/app (unleashedadmin@reserveint...) has been authorized for the Layout Automation API endpoint. Does this authorization extend to all users of the API (the other Social Tables users that  authorize and communicate to Social Tables through our application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the `/4.0/layout-automation` endpoint set is currently gated on the requesting user's team's product access. This means that as of today (9/7), the endpoint will reject requests made with OAuth bearer tokens on behalf of users who do not have access to the product, event if the tokens were issued to an app belonging to a team that has access.

It sounds like your use case involves invoking layout automation on behalf of your end users, and we want to support it. We are treating this lack of access propagation as a bug, and will be rolling out a resolution and responding to this thread as soon as possible.

Thank you for your patience, and for helping us improve our platform.

Comment: We deployed an update this morning to resolve this issue, but due to a bundled platform bug, we were forced to revert it. Please stand by for a resolution to this issue.

Comment: We have re-deployed the resolution. End-user access should be working at this time.